# Bulk Insert Error Messages SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

Is there any way to capture the error messages that occur during a bulk insert?

If I specify an error file, I get 2 seperate files, one that contains the record that errored, and one that contains the row.

The messages that are displayed for errors contain more information:

`Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1, column 6 (temp_batch_date).`

Is it possible to write these messages into a temp table so I can handle them accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`SqlBulkCopy` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) to perform the operation and you should have programmatic access to any errors (exceptions) that are generated.  This should allow you to attempt recovery/logging.

If you don't want to use Visual Studio (why not?  it's [free](http://www.microsoft.com/express)), you could also use [PowerShell](http://chentiangemalc.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/how-to-net-powershell-in-windows-pe-2/).

Handling these errors outside of SQL Server really opens up what/how you can workaround hurdles with your source data.